# Multiplying two matrices from different classes in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two classes matrix1 and matrix2 these two classes reads and prints matrices from a text file and ı want to multiply these two classes' matrices in another class.How can ı do this??

Comment: please show your code you tried and people will be happy to assist you!

Comment: Given Java naming conventions, that classes are named using MixedCase, and variables/fields are named using camelCase, your reference to `matrix1` and `matrix2` would indicate that you are referring to two *instances* of the same class, not two different classes. Is that correct, or are you violating the common Java naming conventions?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the code of your classes, please? It would ease to give you a better answer.

Supposing that those matrix have similar charachteristics, (which I don't know) you could create a parent class with the characteristics in common for the both classes and make the product there.

Or maybe you could create another class, create an instance of every matrix in the new class, take the values from every matrix to be multiplied and apply the mathematic rules for matrix products on that new class.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give specific advice without any code, but one possible solution is to create a third class (named 'MatrixAdder' or something) that has an instance of both the matrix1 and matrix2 classes and can access both of their matrices before multiplying them together.